# Remove a style used in parent theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have a parent theme that calls a function `woc_register_cssjs` that then uses `wp_register_style` within it below to do the business then they kick it into action by using `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woc_register_cssjs');`

The location for this document is `theme/admin/theme-functions.php`

What my issue is that I cannot seem to remove a `css` document that has been added by this script - I have created a child theme and I would like to override the css document.

In my child themes `function.php` I have implemented the following function but its not working and the parent css document is still loading - why?

**Code:**

```
<?php
    // Remove Perent Styles

    function remove_css()
    {
        wp_deregister_style('layout.css');
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_css', 100);

?>
```

**Theme Functions - Parent:**

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Register Scripts and CSS */
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function woc_register_cssjs() {

        //Register Scripts
        wp_register_script('imagesloaded', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js', 'jquery', '1.0', false);
        wp_register_script('customSelect', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.customSelect.min.js', 'jquery', '1.0', false);
        wp_register_script('wocSelect', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/woc.select.js', 'jquery', '1.0', false);
        wp_register_script('waypoints', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/waypoints.min.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('retina', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/retina.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('mobileMenu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/woc.mobile.menu.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('fitvids', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.fitvids.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('touchEffects', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/toucheffects.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('modernizer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/modernizr.custom.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('menu', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/woc.tooltipmenu.min.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.isotope.min.js', 'jquery', '1.1', true);
        wp_register_script('isotope_sloppy_masonry', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.isotope.sloppy-masonry.min.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('shiv', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/html5.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('base', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/base.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('woc_woocommerce', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/woc.woocommerce.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('gmaps', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false', '', '1.0', false);
        wp_register_script('validationEngine', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.validationEngine.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);
        wp_register_script('cycle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.cycle.lite.js', 'jquery', '1.0', true);

        // Register Styles
        wp_register_style('base', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/base.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('framework', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/responsive-gs-12col.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('layout', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/layout.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('dropdowns', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/woc-dropdowns.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('comments', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/comments.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('flexslider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('flexsliderNav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/flexslider-nav.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('fontawesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/font-awesome.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/animate.min.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('isotope', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/isotope.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('portfolio', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/woc-portfolio.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('woocommerce', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/woc-woocommerce.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('modal', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ct-modal-overlay.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('validationEngine', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/validationEngine.jquery.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');
        wp_register_style('pageBuilder', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/page-builder-blocks.css', '', '', 'screen, projection');

    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woc_register_cssjs');

    function woc_init_scripts() {

        // Enqueue Styles
        wp_enqueue_style('base');
        wp_enqueue_style('framework');
        wp_enqueue_style('ie');
        wp_enqueue_style('layout');
        wp_enqueue_style('dropdowns');
        wp_enqueue_style('comments');
        wp_enqueue_style('flexslider');
        wp_enqueue_style('flexsliderNav');
        wp_enqueue_style('fontawesome');
        wp_enqueue_style('animate');
        wp_enqueue_style('isotope');
        wp_enqueue_style('portfolio');
        wp_enqueue_style('pageBuilder');
        wp_enqueue_style('validationEngine');
        wp_enqueue_style('modal');

        // Enqueue Scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('imagesloaded');
        wp_enqueue_script('underscore');
        wp_enqueue_script('waypoints');
        wp_enqueue_script('flexslider');
        wp_enqueue_script('retina');
        wp_enqueue_script('mobileMenu');
        wp_enqueue_script('fitvids');
        wp_enqueue_script('modernizer');
        wp_enqueue_script('touchEffects');
        wp_enqueue_script('menu');
        wp_enqueue_script('isotope');
        wp_enqueue_script('isotope_sloppy_masonry');
        wp_enqueue_script('gmaps');
        wp_enqueue_script('customSelect');
        wp_enqueue_script('wocSelect');
        wp_enqueue_script('shiv');
        wp_enqueue_script('validationEngine');
        wp_enqueue_script('cycle');
        wp_enqueue_script('base');

        if(is_page_template('template-contact.php')) {

        }

        if (is_singular()) {
            wp_enqueue_script( "comment-reply" );
        }

        //script globals
        $woc_script_global = array(
             'site_url' => site_url(),
             'template_url' => get_template_directory_uri(),
             'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ));
        wp_localize_script('base', 'woc_global', $woc_script_global);

        if (is_plugin_active('woocommerce/woocommerce.php')) {
            wp_enqueue_style('woocommerce');
            wp_enqueue_script('woc_woocommerce');
        }

    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woc_init_scripts');
```

Comment: do you want to remove just that single CSS file? If so, can you show the `wp_register_style` code that is specific to it?

Comment: @leftside I want to remove the css file as I have a copy of it in my child theme.  I dont really want to hard remove it as it will  be back if there is a theme update

Comment: right, but to remove it correctly it's an important piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @leftside yes I want to remove the parent layout.css correctly

Comment: Ok, I'll wait until you edit your question with that bit of code. As a "devil's advocate", why not just leave it in your parent theme?

Comment: @leftside What bit of code?  I would like to but its still loading and its not loading the child theme ver

Comment: The bit of code you showed, that came from the parent's functions.php, correct?

Comment: @leftside No I wrote that in my child theme function.php.  Do you want me to post the 2 parent functions?

Comment: yes, that is what we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
wp_deregister_style( 'layout' );
```